# How to Pass Query in Jquery to Update mongoDB?

Tags: jquery, mongodb

Records not updated

```
var k =  { $set: {            symbol:symbol,
                              tquan: "12333"
                            }
                    }

$.ajax( {
 type: "POST" ,
 url: "http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/stocks/?q={symbol:"+symbol+"}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data:JSON.stringify(k),
dataType: "json"
 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  You'd think that would be possible but turns out that MongoDB out-of-the box only supports **READ-ONLY** operations with its native REST API.  If you want to update/write documents you just have to pick from one of these [REST interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/).

From the official [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-interface):

> The mongod process includes a simple REST interface as a convenience.
>   With no support for insert, update, or remove operations, it is
>   generally used for monitoring, alert scripts, and administrative
>   tasks. For full REST capabilities, consider using an external REST
>   Interface such as Sleepy.Mongoose.